# code build to create lambda layer - cannot find module

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I want package a lambda layer using codebuild.

My codebuild buildspec is as follows:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10  
    commands:
      - npm init -y
      - npm install --save middy
artifacts:
  files:
    - 'node_modules/**/*'
    - 'package-lock.json'
    - 'package.json'
```

This saves a `nodejs.zip` folder to my s3 bucket

the resulting zip file looks like this:

[image: folder dir]

[image: middy is here]

package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "src",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "middy": "^0.30.4"
  }
}
```

however when I add this layer to my lambda (node10.x)

and import my mods:

```
'use strict';
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const middy = require('middy')
const { cors } = require('middy/middlewares')
```

Returns the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'middy'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/function_code/verify_zipcode.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'middy'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/function_code/verify_zipcode.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)",
    "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11"
  ]
}
```

Adding the envoronment variable:
`NODE_PATH : ./:/opt/node_modules` gave my lambda access to my layers, but lost the context of `aws-sdk`

After adding the env var I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/function_code/verify_zipcode.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/function_code/verify_zipcode.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)",
    "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11"
  ]
}
```

**Is there a way to use both the native `aws-sdk` and my layers? Or do I need to use an `aws-sdk` layer anytime I use other custom layers?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory structure of a node.js layer (nodejs.zip in your example) should be:

```
├── nodejs
  └── package.json
  └── node_modules
          └── middy(version z.z.z)
```

Update your buildspec file to add a parent nodejs folder:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10  
    commands:
      - mkdir nodejs           # NEW LINE
      - cd nodejs              # NEW LINE
      - npm init -y
      - npm install bcrypt

artifacts:
  files:
    - 'nodejs/**/*'            # CHANGE LINE
    - 'package.json'
```

and remove the environment variable:
`NODE_PATH`

Comment: When the nodejs.zip unzips it is inside a nodejs folder - does it need to be nodejs/nodejs/...

Comment: I didn't see any nodejs folder when you wrote this **the resulting zip file looks like this:**

Comment: That's because I was browsing the zip file in windows 10, I hadn't unzipped it. When you unzip a folder it automatically puts the contents inside a folder with the same name as the zip folder

Comment: Let's call your zip nodejs_test, when you unzip it you should see nodejs->node_modules, when you  browsing the zip file in windows 10 first dir should be nodejs

Comment: if I call is nodejs_test.zip when I unzip it I'll see nodejs_test/node_modules

Comment: nodejs_test/nodejs/node_modules is the layer stracture, change your directory structure. **does it need to be nodejs/nodejs/...** - Yes

Comment: okay so I need to have nodejs/nodejs then -- I'll give it a shot